# FeathersJS: REST authentication of an OAuth user

Tags: oauth-2.0, feathersjs, feathers-authentication

I've created a FeathersJS backend app and a React frontend app. I'm using OAuth2 strategy to authenticate users to my own WordPress site. Everything is working fine. But now I'd like the users to be able to access my FeathersJS backend REST API, but as they authenticate through the WordPress OAuth2 server, thus following all the OAuth2 authentication process through my React frontend app, which would be the correct FeathersJS way to allow the users authenticate to my backend so that they can do REST API calls?

Answer (score 0):

> But now I'd like the users to be able to access my FeathersJS backend REST API

To let people access your backend REST API (which I assume is only possible after they authenticate), you need to check whether the access token they have is, in fact, valid with the third party auth provider.

You can directly let them use the back end API. In case the API doesn't find a valid access token with the incoming request, it will redirect it to the login page. After which, now the backend can validate itself with third-party OAuth provider and return the result.

> following all the OAuth2 authentication process through my React frontend app

It is recommended to not do all the OAuth check from front-end since this exposes the access-token on the user agent, which might be a serious issue. See this:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2#grant-type-implicit

Comment: Hello Akash, sorry, I think I didn't explain my problem clearly enough. I don't want to create a new OAuth server client for each user (with it's own redirect URI and clientID and clientSecret...) so that my users can get their access token on their own, and then send it to my FeathersJS REST API to validate it, but I'd like my users to need only the FeathersJS REST API to access it, as they were "local" users (local users only need an email and a password) and not OAuth users. I'd like that OAuth users behave like "local" users in FeathersJS REST API. Do you have any other solution in mind?